# What's the use of the "attrs" parameter in an angular directive link function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-directive

Considering this directive :

```
.directive('myDirective', function(httpRequestTracker) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            myvar: "=",
        },
        link: function($scope, elem, attrs) {
            console.log($scope.myvar, attrs.myvar);
        }
    };
})
```

and this JS console output :

> > undefined undefined // if no attribute
>
> > value value // if attribute value = "value"

What is the use of the `attr` parameter of the `link` function ?  What is the difference with $scope ?

Thanks

Comment: You should use scope.myvar (not $scope.myvar) to get value which you pass to the directive. Also in link function use scope, not $scope. The following link might be useful: https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-understanding-isolate-scope. Take a look to other videos about directives.

Comment: hmm scope or $scope is just a naming convention here, I could have just called the first parameter "superHeroScope" and use it like that.

Comment: Have you tried to use scope instead of $scope and it does not work for you?

Comment: both ways works -_- I'm asking why is the utility of this third parameter. post edited, it was not so clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`attrs` is just a raw list of attributes on a directive
`scope` is more sophisticated, you can use three different operators to populate it with values:

- `=` evaluates expression in HTML, and may contain objects
- `@` interprets value passed as string. always.
- `&` gives you access to functions defined on parent scope

Comment: To add to this, there can be attributes available in `attrs` that are not being made available in `scope.` Ex: `<div myvar="someval" width="200px">` "myvar" will be bound to `scope` because you've done so in your directive definition but both "myvar" and "width" will be available in `attrs`

Comment: Thanks for both the answer and your comment ;)

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm quite late to the party, but for posterity's sake, the most crucial difference to me is that using `scope: {...}` in the directive's definition object (not the link function signature) creates an isolate scope within the directive element, whereas omitting the `scope` property altogether and manually retrieving values from `attrs` does not. There are plenty of cases where, for whatever reason, you don't want to make a new scope but you still need the value of some attribute.